# How to mirror a p2 repository which requires authentication

Tags: eclipse, p2

I know how to mirror a p2 repository (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Repository_Mirroring), however, my repository requires authentication. How do I provide the credentials to the mirror application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that's very recent issue: [How to specify credentials to p2-repositories requiring authentication?](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/556492/)

Looks like there are no workaround :(